# State Monad to save board in game

Tags: haskell, monads, state-monad

I have a module `Game` that defines a method play like this `play :: Board -> Move - > Board`.

I want to use State Monad in another module called `Playing` that imports the `Game` module so that I can call `play` from there on a loop until the `Board` reaches a certain state.

I want to call the method with play with the `Board` that I get from the State Monad and then update the State Monad value with the `Board` returned by `play`.

So while the loop is going on I want to receive moves to apply to the `play` method and my current state.

But I'm quite lost as in how achieving this in a way that the module `Game` has no idea that I'm using a State Monad.

I have been looking at quite a few tutorials and examples (like [this](https://acm.wustl.edu/functional/state-monad.php), [this](https://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/Haskell/Understanding_monads/State), [this](http://brandon.si/code/the-state-monad-a-tutorial-for-the-confused/), etc) and I feel like I understand the way in which State Monad it's applied there but apparently not well enough as to abstract it to this particular implementation.

```
playing :: IO ()
playing = do
            putStr $ "The board looks like:"
            board <- get
            putStr $ showBoard  board 
            putStr $ "Indicate a move:"
            move <- getLine
            if validMove move then do
                newBoard <- play board (getMove move)
                if gameEnded newBoard then do
                    putStr $ "You win!" --stop the execution
                else do
                    put newBoard
            else do
               putStr $ "Invalid move"
```

I want `playing` to be on a loop until it gets a particular `Board` that means the game ended. And use the State Monad to send the current `Board` to `play` and to the other methods in the `Game` module like `gameEnded :: Board -> Bool`, `showBoard :: Board -> String` and 'getMove :: String -> Move'.

Any help is welcome

Comment: I don't understand what you're asking. Is there a particular function you're having trouble writing?

Comment: @melpomene I edited my question to include something more specific, I'm having trouble writing `playing`

Comment: @moondaisy Where are your `Move`s coming from? Your iteration will be based on that source. Do you want `playing` to check the board state and return an indication of whether the game is over, or will `playing` simply update the board state and the caller will decide whether to apply another move or terminate?

Comment: @ryachza I could get the moves by reading a `Char` from the console using. I guess I could write a caller that uses `IO` starts `playing` and gets the moves and shows the resulting `Board` until it decides the game has ended, in that case `playing` could return an indicator.

Comment: @ryachza I just included a more detailed pseudo code of what `playing` should do, but I don't know how to handle the State Monad part nor what the firm of `playing` should be

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you swap the order of arguments to `play`, you have a function of type:

```
Move -> Board -> Board
```

Which you can partially apply with a `Move` to get one of type:

```
Board -> Board
```

You can convert this to an action on `State` using `modify :: (s -> s) -> State s ()` to modify the board:

```
playing :: Move -> State Board ()
playing move = modify (play move)
```

One solution here is monad transformers—sounds scarier than it is. You could use `StateT` over `IO`, the `StateT` to store the game state and the `IO` to prompt the user for moves. For example:

```
import Control.Monad.Trans.Class (lift)
import Control.Monad.Trans.State (evalStateT, gets, modify)

-- Get a move from the user.
getMove :: IO Move
getMove = do
  line <- getLine
  -- (Your implementation of parsing moves here.)

-- The initial state of the board.
initialBoard :: Board
initialBoard = -- ...

-- Whether the board represents a completed game.
boardDone :: Board -> Bool
boardDone board = -- ...

-- Main game loop.
gameLoop :: IO ()
gameLoop = evalStateT loop initialBoard
  where
    loop = do
      move <- lift getMove
      modify (play move)
      done <- gets boardDone
      if done then pure () else loop
```

You use `lift` to convert a normal `IO` action into a `StateT Board IO` action, `modify :: (Monad m) => (s -> s) -> StateT s m ()` to modify the state, and `gets :: (Monad m) => (s -> a) -> StateT s m a` to read properties of the current state. `loop` either tail-calls itself to continue playing, or else returns.

Using the structure and names in your edited question:

```
playing :: IO ()
playing = evalStateT loop initialBoard
  where

    loop :: StateT Board IO ()
    loop = do
      printBoard
      move <- lift promptMove
      modify (play move)
      ended <- gets gameEnded
      if ended
        then lift $ putStrLn "You win!"
        else loop

    printBoard :: StateT Board IO ()
    printBoard = do
      lift $ putStrLn $ "The board looks like:"
      board <- get
      lift $ putStrLn $ showBoard board

    promptMove :: IO Move
    promptMove = do
      putStr "Indicate a move: "
      move <- getLine
      if validMove move
        then pure $ getMove move
        else do
          putStrLn "Invalid move."
          promptMove
```

Comment: Thanks, it definitely works. What I don't understand is what does `pure` does?

Comment: @moondaisy: With `pure :: Applicative f => a -> f a`, `pure x` is an action that just returns `x`. It has the same meaning as `return :: Monad m => a -> m a`, which exists for historical reasons: `Applicative` didn’t use to be a superclass of `Monad`. You can use whichever one you prefer. I tend to use `pure` because it has a more general type: `pure` works works for either `Applicative` or `Monad`, but `return` only works for `Monad`.